# state property undefined in render function

Tags: react-native

In the render function on one of my views I am trying to have the opacity of a view be tied to a state property: this.state.infoOpacity.

This is turning an error "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.infoOpacity')"

Any guidance would be helpful.

```
export default class BookView extends Component
{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hideInfo:false,
      infoOpacity:0.80,
      swiperWidth:Dimensions.get('window').width,
      swiperHeight:Dimensions.get('window').height
    };
  }

  render() {
    pages.forEach(function(ranPage){
      photoViews.push(
        <View key={ranPage.letter} style={{width: Dimensions.get('window').width, height: Dimensions.get('window').height}}>
            <View style={[styles.meow,{opacity: this.state.infoOpacity}]}>
              <Text style={styles.text}>{ranPage.name}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.text}>{ranPage.phonetic}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.text2}>{ranPage.description}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
      )
    });


    return (
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <Swiper showsButtons={false} style={{backgroundColor:'#000'}} width={this.state.swiperWidth} height={this.state.swiperHeight}>
            {photoViews}
        </Swiper>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context changed in your forEach function. Use an arrow function to fix your issue. So instead of

`pages.forEach(function(ranPage){ ... });`

write this

`pages.forEach((ranPage) => { ... });`

Comment: That was exactly it! Thank you! Do you know of any good reading about react native context I could do so I don't make this mistake again?

Comment: it has actually nothing to do with react native itself, but rather with javascript. Just use arrow functions all the time, it's almost always the right choice, for now :)

Comment: You could also use infamous `bind` function to not to lose your context. Then your `forEach` function should have looked like `pages.forEach(function(ranPage){photoViews.push(..some JSX here...)}.bind(this));` However instead of this, using arrow function is a better fix.